# Unserializing large Blobs from the Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I store large Blobs in the datastore. These are XML files that can be as large as 20mb. Storing a single 20mb XML file is fine, however the issue comes when I need to unserialize it.

There are all sorts of limitations to this:

- I cannot read more than 1mb from Blobstore
- even if I could I'm still confronted with the 5mb RAM limitation (since I need to put all the XML into RAM before unserializing it)

How would you say I can handle this? I'm open to all sorts of solutions, but hopefully not something that involves using another hosting provider.

Comment: The blob is just plain/text XML

Comment: What 5MB ram limitation? And what do you need to do with the data?

Comment: (To clarify, there isn't and never has been any sort of '5mb ram limitation')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch to a [Sax](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/parsers/SAXParser.html) Parser, streaming the data from the Blobstore with the [BlobstoreInputStream](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream.html) class.
These libraries should help you to avoid the GAE RAM restriction.

Comment: XML was just an example. Imagine it being data that is larger than 5mb when unserialized. Even using these libs, if the data is large enough, it will go over the 5mb limit.

Comment: @Luca If you have different requirements, you need to state them, rather than expecting us to guess.

Answer (score 0):

go with [GAE BackEnd](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html) they do not have configurable memory limit.